# Move <script> to JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jquery which wrote in my HTML between `<script>` tag:

```
  $("#u").focusout(function(){
  $("#u").focus();
});
```

I want to move it to my js file, so I wrote it in a JS file, and put in the head section of the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJS.js"></script>
```

But now my jquery functions don't work. What can be the reason?

Comment: Where was the `<script>` tag in your HTML?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: It seems like you may have included your script before you included the jQuery script. The script tag that includes your script must be after the script tag that includes the jQuery script.

Comment: did you check that you `myJs.js` file is found or showing you a 404 while loading?

Comment: "But now my jquery functions don't work. What can be the reason?" Surely console will tell you

Comment: Error? Not working is not a realy good starting point to try and solve your problem. Could you press F12 in the browser (Firefox or Chrome I like best) and check if there are errors in script or trying to load script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#u").focusout(function(){
      jQuery("#u").focus();
 });});
```

and please load this file after jquery lib

Answer (score 2):

There try to put under $(function(){ like

```
$(function() {
     $("#u").focusout(function(){
          $("#u").focus();
     });
});
```

And check whether your js file is loading or not

Comment: Haha I given ans first but another got as accepted...funny

Answer (score 1):

There are two likely causes for this (and without seeing a preview link it's difficult to tell you which):

In your HTML markup, you need to ensure that you include jQuery before your JavaScript file:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="myJS.js"></script>
```

Or, it may be that your JavaScript is 'firing' before the page has fully loaded.  It is best-practice to ensure that your jQuery is wrapped in a `document.ready` function.  Try replacing your current JavaScript with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#u").focusout(function(){
        $("#u").focus();
    });
});
```

This will ensure that your JavaScript doesn't try and fire before the page is ready (and jQuery is loaded).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to include the jQuery js-file **before** your own js file.
Then, if your js file is included before the #u - element, jquery searches for a non-existing element. To avoid this you should put this code in your js file:

```
$(function() {
   $("#u").focusout(function(){
      $("#u").focus();
   });
});
```

the `$(function(){/*code*/});` makes jQuery wait for the site is full loaded(and also your #u element), so the element will be found by jQuery and the focusout handler can be hooked.